# How do I omit a page with just a catagory

Tags: templating, categories

I have a channel with content and I want to only display content from a certain category.

Should I use a slug? Just trying to wrap my head around this.

This is what I have now:

```
    {% for product in craft.entries.find({section: 'Product', limit:'4',}) %}

    {% for image in product.photo %}
        <img src="{{ image.getUrl('bottom') }}" />
        <p><a href="{{ product.url }}">Link to pants!</a></p>
        <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
        <p>{{ product.price }}</p>
        <p>{{ category.title }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://buildwithcraft.com/help/entries-related-to-category

Comment: Thanks Jamie. How do I pull entry detail from that category I filtered out?